# Simple jQuery accordion that can track height changes to animate other objects alongside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I needed to create an accordion that could keep track of the adjustments it made to height. In most cases, an accordion's container will adjust its height automatically, but my accordion was in an absolutely positioned div that was within a relatively positioned div, and I needed to adjust the height of the relatively positioned div along with the accordion to move some background images around. In case anyone else ever needs something similar, here is the result I came up with (with the help of ahren and dmi3y):

http://jsfiddle.net/MSatE/48/

The html:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Sample Header 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Sample<br />
            More Sample Text<br />
            Yet More Sample Text<br />
            I wish I could come up with something more clever<br />
            This should be enough for you to see the problem
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Sample Header 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Sample<br />
            More Sample Text<br />
            Yet More Sample Text<br />
            I wish I could come up with something more clever<br />
            This should be enough for you to see the problem Sample<br />
            More Sample Text<br />
            Yet More Sample Text<br />
            I wish I could come up with something more clever<br />
            This should be enough for you to see the problem
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#accordion {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-bottom: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #C0C0C0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #C0C0C0;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #FFF;
}

#accordion h3 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    padding: 10px;
}

#accordion div {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    background: #F4F4F4;
}

#accordion p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#accordion h3:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.forMeasure {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block!important;
}
```

The javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#accordion h3').click(function(){
    var adjustment = 0;
    var div = $(this).next('div');

    if(div.css('display') == 'none')
    {
        adjustment += div.addClass('forMeasure').outerHeight();
        div.removeClass('forMeasure');
        div.slideDown();
        div.siblings('div').each(function(){
            if($(this).css('display') == 'block')
            {
                adjustment -= $(this).outerHeight();
                $(this).slideUp();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        adjustment -= div.outerHeight();
        div.slideUp();
    }
});
```

Comment: **tldr;** - consider creating a small test-case for your problem if you can. It'll take anyone 5-10mins to read through and understand your question as it currently stands.

Comment: Good point, thanks - I edited the post.

Comment: You seriously expected someone to _read_ all of that?

Comment: It has gotten a lot longer since the initial question. I tend to err on the side of verbosity. That is after all what the instructions told me to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simplified your accordion...

http://jsfiddle.net/MSatE/3/

```
$('#accordion h3').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideDown().siblings('div').slideUp();
});​
```

The only CSS change I made:

```
#accordion div {
    position: relative; /* <-- changed to relative */
    display:none; /* <-- changed from visibility:hidden; to display:none; */
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    background: #F4F4F4;
}
```

**EDIT**

As requested... a method to retrieve the new height of the accordion before animation begins...
http://jsfiddle.net/MSatE/6/

```
$('#accordion h3').click(function(){
    /* Extra code to get the height of the new accordion once this div has been shown... */
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.siblings('div').filter(':visible').addClass('oldVisible');
    $t.next().show().siblings('div').hide();
    var height = $('#accordion').outerHeight();
    $t.next().hide().siblings('.oldVisible').show().removeClass('oldVisible');

    console.log(height);
    $t.next().slideDown().siblings('div').slideUp();
});​
```

Comment: I need the more complicated stuff because I have to get the height of the div while it's invisible in order to animate another element by the same amount simultaneously. At least I think I need it. I could be wrong.

Comment: why? `#content` should expand automatically.

Comment: not when #div1 is positioned absolutely

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-think your CSS design. You're just making it hard for yourself currently.

Comment: I'm doing a lot of extra work for an animation I don't need. But I want it, and in order to do the animation I need to do the CSS that way. If anyone can figure out how get the jsfiddle example to not have the text escape the accordion, that's all I really need. I don't think the larger CSS structure really has anything to do with the issue. The problem is probably just with my jquery. I just gave the lengthy explanation because I knew people would say 'just use jquery-ui'.

Comment: jQuery-ui is too verbose for a simple accordion, as I've demonstrated in my above code.

Comment: I agree - do you know why the paragraph is escaping the accordion in the jsfiddle I linked? Or do you know of another way I can get the accordion to work and to also get the heights of the hidden elements?

Comment: this is working solution, I meant this answer, just bit improvement over there http://jsfiddle.net/MSatE/5/, not sure why it is not suite

Comment: @ahren I like your one-liner accordion though. It's better than my two-liner I usually use!

Comment: @dmi3y - your solution doesn't close other currently open `div`'s. I do like your thinking though! Always looking for improvement in even the most simple things is a good way to look at life, and code.

Comment: It may be a working solution to other people's problems, but not to mine. I need to get the heights of the divs while they are hidden and simultaneously animate other elements as the accordion expands and contracts.

Comment: okay, gotcha how about that http://jsfiddle.net/MSatE/7/

Comment: @dnag - I've included a method to retrieve the height of the whole accordion once the new div has been expanded...

Comment: Thanks you two! Between your responses I found a much better way to approach it. dmi3y's class addition and removal is great, and I didn't even know outerHeight existed. And I like ahren's 1-liner to handle the actual animation. I will have to make it a little more intelligent for my purposes, but you guys gave me a much better start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you examined the [jQueryUI accordion feature](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?  If not, take a look at their examples, copy/paste them into a doc on your web site, and spend ten minutes playing with it. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have - I was originally using a jquery-ui accordion before I added in these animations. I've used them many times. But in this instance it is difficult at my level of expertise to accomplish the coordinated animation like I mention above. Jsfiddle coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have altered your jquery a small bit to get what i think you are asking for. Basically now the height of the content div covers all of the content in it. http://jsfiddle.net/MSatE/9/

Was very simple when looking at it just had to adjust the following line to 100%:

```
var div_height = $(this).height();
$(this).css('height', '100%');
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!
Regards,
-Epik-

Comment: The jsfiddle actually isn't working for me, but I got the answer I needed. Thanks for the reply!